# What's different about add-on items?

Tags: amazon

Today I noticed that Amazon now has [add-on items](http://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html/?nodeId=200876660):
[image: "The item is available because of the new Add-on program: The Add-on program allows Amazon to offer thousands of low-priced items that would be cost-prohibitive to ship on their own. These items ship with qualifying orders over $25 and are eligible for free shipping.]

How is this any different from the normal [Super Saver Shipping](http://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=527692)? They both just seem to say that shipping's free on orders over $25. Is there a difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, I just figured it out. It's not just that Add-ons get free shipping on orders over $25, but they get no shipping at all on orders under $25:
[image: A $9.98 Add-on item with me unable to Proceed to Checkout][image: Me able to Proceed to Checkout after adding a $59.98 item]